# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Earth Science Stack Exchange](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: First time participating in a site self-evaluation so I'm curious, does someone know if the 10 questions are the same for every reviewer?

Comment: @plannapus yes they are. And exactly 8 days after the start of the evaluation (so that should be 2014-10-28 03:02 UTC), a net score is produced for each of the ten questions, and the Community bot posts the table of results in an answer, and accepts that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How many joules are required to mine a unit of coal?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/how-many-joules-are-required-to-mine-a-unit-of-coal)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [During the "Ice Ages" or "Snowball Earth" times, where was all the energy?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/during-the-ice-ages-or-snowball-earth-times-where-was-all-the-energy)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Lake inflow-outflow problem](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/lake-inflow-outflow-problem)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Looking at ocean depth/latitude profiles of dissolved oxygen and nitrate. Why is dissolved oxygen low when nitrate is high?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/looking-at-ocean-depth-latitude-profiles-of-dissolved-oxygen-and-nitrate-why-is)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Interpretation of a seismogram (three components)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/interpretation-of-a-seismogram-three-components)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why do Euler poles for plate motions not stay fixed in time?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/why-do-euler-poles-for-plate-motions-not-stay-fixed-in-time)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why do gold deposits form only in certain areas of the earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/why-do-gold-deposits-form-only-in-certain-areas-of-the-earth)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Sea breeze - magnitude of horizontal pressure gradient?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/sea-breeze-magnitude-of-horizontal-pressure-gradient)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is the atmosphere becoming thicker?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/is-the-atmosphere-becoming-thicker)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How did this rock dome (pictured) form?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-did-this-rock-dome-pictured-form)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

Answer (score 3):

Several of the questions failed to appear in the first two pages of google results.

In a couple of other cases, the answer here was no better than resources elsewhere.

But in some cases, the question, answer(s) and search-engine visibility all looked very good to me.

Comment: Very similar experience here.